# How to include pure text to children iterable?

Tags: javascript, html

There is `span` that contains different tags and pure text. I need to get pure text in order to do replace some word to other and the same time save tags.

In case `span.children`, text is ignoring. Is there way to iterable such items?

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('span').children)
```

```html
<span>
  <p>Ignore text</p>
  target text 1
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" />
  target text 2
</span>
```

I mean the next result:

```html
<!-- From -->
<span>
    <p>Ignore text</p>
    target text 1
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
    target text 2
</span>

<!-- To -->
<span>
    <p>Ignore text</p>
    new text 1
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
    new text 2
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate over the `childNodes` and check if `nodeType` is text or not.

**Demo:**

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span');

//iterate over the child nodes
for (const node of span.childNodes) {
  //check if the node is a text node
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    //replace the partial text content
    const newText = node.textContent.replace('target text', 'new text');
    //replace the old text with the text
    node.textContent = newText
  }
}

console.log(span.innerHTML.trim());
```

```html
<span>
  <p>Ignore text</p>
  target text 1
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" />
  target text 2
</span>
```

Comment: You can edit text of text nodes, you don't need to replace them. After you have `newText` you can do `node.textContent = newText`